# VScode version doesnt match latest python version on system

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, debian-buster

I have recently installed debian10 and VSCode. I have checked the currently installed version of python on my system is and it is python 3.7.3. This is also the version returned by python --version. When running python --version in terminal of vscode it returns python 3.8.8. When i go to select the python interpreter it only gives me options to select python 3.8.8. If i specify the path python i am currently using(python 3.7.3) it does not recognize it, or the other python versions there, which include python 2.7 etc. The path is /usr/bin . please help, ive been strugling with this for so long now.

Comment: Have you tried to [manually](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) specify the interpreter?

Comment: Yes i entered the path to the file containing my binaries as well as the different python versions i.e. /usr/bin, but this did not work. I also included the following in settings.json "python.pythonPath": "/bin/python" which did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating to the newest version of python? If not, try and it should work fine after.